# How to assign programatically "include virtual" to asp.net dropdownlist items?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdownlist in an ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstField1" runat="server">
<!--#include virtual="../path/to/myListOfValues.asp"-->
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Contents of "myListOfValues.asp" file:

```
<asp:ListItem value="%">Select value</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="1">Value #1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="2">Value #2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="3">Value #3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem value="4">Value #4</asp:ListItem>
```

At some point of the page's execution, I change the items of this dropdownlist. But, eventually, i need to reload the items from the .asp file.

is there any way to "restore" the items from the .asp file, i.e. changing the dropdownlist's "innerHTML"  or something like that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found a way: 
1) Having a delimited string with the values i need to exclude from the items.

2) Splitting the delimited string

3) Looping the resultant array, and

4) Searching for the value in the dropdownlist. If the value is found, I disable it.

Something just like this:

```
'split the excluded items list
Dim arrExcludedItems() As String = myExcludedList.Split("|")

'enable all the dropdownlist's items.
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.lstField1.Items.Count - 1
Me.lstField1.Items(i).Enabled = True
Next

'search for the excluded item in the dropdownlist
'if it's found, disable the respective item.
For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(arrExcludedItems)
Me.lstField1.Items.FindByValue(arrExcludedItems(i)).Enabled = False
Next
```

Hope it helps for anyone.

Best regards,

Comment: I don't think you can mix classic asp and webforms like that.

Comment: @VDWWD --> It is possible. The first time the page is loaded, the dropdownlist takes its values from the .asp file. If you don't change the items from the dropdownlist, no problem. But if i change the items, I dunno how to restore them from the asp file without opening the file, looping its contents, adding the contents to the dropdownlist ...

Comment: Hmmm I did not know that. But I would still recommend using the 'normal' way. Like binding from the aspx code behind file.

Comment: @VDWWD  agree with you (the "normal" way) but that was the scenario i faced ( a legacy ) Thanks for your kind comments !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing. I could not figure out how to rebind data from an asp file. But that does not mean you cannot achieve what you want. This snippet stores the original ListItems in ViewState so that you can bind the orignal ones later on.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstField1" runat="server">
    <!--#include virtual="/myListOfValues.asp"-->
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Bind new data" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Bind original data" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a new list to hold the original listitems
    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    //loop all the listitems and add them to the list
    foreach (ListItem item in lstField1.Items)
    {
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Value, item.Text));
        Response.Write(item.Text);
    }

    //add the list to viewstate for later usage
    ViewState["tempList"] = list;

    //clear the list of its current items
    lstField1.Items.Clear();

    //add the new items to the dropdownlist
    lstField1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" });
    lstField1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "Item 2", Value = "2" });
}


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load the list from viewstate and cast it back to a keyvalue list
    var list = ViewState["tempList"] as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;

    //clear the list of its current items
    lstField1.Items.Clear();

    //add the original items to the dropdownlist
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        lstField1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = item.Value, Value = item.Key });
    }
}
```